# Why is npm module not found immediately after installing it?

Tags: node.js, npm, newman

See here - newman was already installed.  what could be missing?  I tried with and without admin permissions as well:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g newman
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman -> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin\newman.js
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- newman@3.8.3

C:\Windows\system32>newman
'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Check your path. Google for "windows npm path".

Comment: i've done this and the problem persists.

Comment: reinstalled node.js and works

Answer (score 3):

Your question look like Node is missing from the *SYSTEM PATH*, do the following, it should resolve it.

1. Click the Start button, then click **Control Panel**
2. Click **User Accounts**
   [image: User Account]
   [image: User]
3. Click **Change my environment variables**
   [image: Variable]
4. Select **PATH** and click the *Edit...* button
   [image: Path]
5. At the end of the Variable value, add `;C:\Program Files\nodejs` or `;C:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs`
6. Click *Ok* on the "Edit User Variable" window, then click *Ok* on the **Environment Variables** window
7. Start a command prompt window (Start button, then type **cmd** into the search and hit enter)
8. At the prompt (`C:\>`) type **npm** and hit enter; you should now see some help text (`Usage: npm <command>` etc.) rather than "*npm is not recognized...*"

Or simply run this in your command line as an admin

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

and then try running `node`

To be very clean, create a new system variable `NODEJS`

```
NODEJS="C:\Program Files\Nodejs"
```

If none of the above fix your problem, I'll suggest you remove the install NODEJS from your computer and reinstall it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Node.js for Windows, you can find a new entry in the Start menu: "Node.js command prompt". Let's look into the batch file linked to this entry, we see the executed command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"
```

So this is a kind of suggestion to work with Node.js in the command line - by this link. But you can use this line for your favorite terminal application in the startup arguments.